# How do I directly reference a table column in a database relationship?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Ok, my google-fu fails me. I want to have 2 relationships specified in a single table. Specifically, in the code below, I want to have the User.written field reference directly to the Article.author_id field since it's problem seems to be that User.written can't decide whether to reference Article.author_id or Article.reviewed_by

The traceback:

```
>>> User.query.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nick/.virtualenvs/npl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 426, in __get__
    mapper = orm.class_mapper(type)
  File "/home/nick/.virtualenvs/npl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 379, in class_mapper
    mapper = _inspect_mapped_class(class_, configure=configure)
  File "/home/nick/.virtualenvs/npl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 358, in _inspect_mapped_class
    mapper._configure_all()
  File "/home/nick/.virtualenvs/npl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1145, in _configure_all
    configure_mappers()
  File "/home/nick/.virtualenvs/npl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2566, in configure_mappers
    raise e
InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.written - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

My app/models.py:

```
class Article(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Miscellanious details
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))  #<--here
    namespace = db.Column(db.String(6), unique=True)
    date_submitted = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    status = db.Column(db.Enum('pending', 'approved', 'rejected'))
    date_reviewed = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=True)
    reviewed_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'),  #<--here
                            nullable=True)


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))  # Differentiate between users and moderators.
    written = db.relationship('Rental', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')  #<--here

#something like db.relationship(column='articles.author_id') would be great
```

I'm using flask with SQLAlchemy. I hope I gave enough information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`foreign_keys` argument to `relationship`](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.foreign_keys).

```
class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    reviewer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    author = db.relationship(User, foreign_keys=author_id, backref='written')
    reviewer = db.relationship(User, foreign_keys=reviewer_id, backref='reviewed')
```

*For simplicity's sake, I keep the relationship in the same model as the foreign key, so it's easier to tell where things are.*  So remove the `User.written` relationship now that it is the backref of the `Article.author` relationship